Is there a way to change the ffplay playback speed while running
I am trying to modify ffplay 7.0 to allow us to modify the playback speed while running. Our use-case only involves basic video-only mp4 files.
We can set the playback speed with something like the following:
ffplay -i ..\Video\SampleVideoLong.mp4 -vf "setpts=5.0*PTS" -loglevel debug -sync video
But I don't know how to change that option "live" (note if I don't choose -sync video, it gets very laggy - but that's fine as our use-case is video only.
I have tried the following (with just a fixed rate at the moment):
        {
            static double l_CurrentSpeed = 1.0;
            double l_NewSpeed = 2.0;
            double l_Diff = l_NewSpeed / l_CurrentSpeed;
            double l_ClockSpeed = cur_stream->extclk.speed;
            double l_NewClockSpeed = l_ClockSpeed * l_Diff;
            av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_DEBUG,
                "Changing speed from %f to %f\n",
                l_ClockSpeed, l_NewClockSpeed
                );

            set_clock_speed(&cur_stream->vidclk, l_NewClockSpeed);
            //set_clock(&cur_stream->vidclk, l_NewClockSpeed, cur_stream->extclk.serial);
            l_CurrentSpeed = l_NewSpeed;
        }

I've set both the pts (set_clock()) and the "speed" (set_clock_speed()), but neither of these had any effect.
Would I need to something extra, or is there a way to update the setpts expression in the video filter from ffplay?
Note the metadata of the file we are trying with is:
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '..\Video\SampleVideoLong.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf61.1.100
  Duration: 00:18:10.56, start: 0.160000, bitrate: 1755 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und), 1, 1/90000: Video: mpeg2video (Main), 1 reference frame (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive, left), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 1754 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn (default)
      Metadata:
        handler_name    : VideoHandler
        vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
        encoder         : XDCAM EX 1080p25
      Side data:
        cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 278528 vbv_delay: N/A

I believe the files we'll be using should have identical or similar metadata.

The setpts filter accepts commands, so you can add a zmq filter to change the setpts expr.

We are hoping to do it "internally" (i.e. by modifying ffplay). The zmq filter appears to be for external commands - can it also be used for internal commands, or is there a way to do it the same way that zmq does it?

What you could try is 1) add a float parameter to VideoState e.g. speed initialized to 1.0 2) add two key events in event_loop(), which when triggered change the parameter by some fixed amount up or down, 3) in video_thread(), multiply frame_rate with the parameter just before av_buffersrc_add_frame()

Thanks! That looks like it should work. Will test that tomorrow. As it happens, we were already using event_loop() to detect keys - which is why we wanted to stick with something similar.

@Gyan Oddly, that doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've added a debug comment, and frame_rate is definitely being modified (between 50/1, 25/1, and 25/2). But the speed isn't changing. I tried just manually dividing duration (lower down) by 2.0, but that also didn't make any difference.
